# Eclipse tomcat server not picking up updates

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using tomcat in Eclipse IDE . I have few html files in my project . When I modify these files from outside Eclipse using other editors such as notepad++, tomcat server doesn't pick up changes until I reopen them in Eclipse IDE. 
What could be causing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Files can't be published to Tomcat by Eclipse until Eclipse knows they've changed. You can manually Refresh them from the File menu (or the folder they're in, or the project, or the entire workspace), or try turning on automatic refreshes on the `Workspace` preference page.